# item:save events are triggered twice when an item is created

Tags: events

I'm trying to log item events like - on item created, on item saved etc.

**patch.config:**

```
<events>
   <event name="item:created">
      <handler type="Basiscore.CmsAudit.Handlers.ItemEventHandler, Basiscore.CmsAudit" method="OnItemCreated"/>
   </event>      
   <event name="item:saving">
      <handler type="Basiscore.CmsAudit.Handlers.ItemEventHandler, Basiscore.CmsAudit" method="OnItemSaving"/>
   </event>
   <event name="item:saved">
      <handler type="Basiscore.CmsAudit.Handlers.ItemEventHandler, Basiscore.CmsAudit" method="OnItemSaved"/>
   </event>      
</events>
```

**ItemEventHandler.cs:**

```
public class ItemEventHandler
{
  public void OnItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     Item createdItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
         if (createdItem == null)
           return;

         Log.Info("ITEM CREATED");        
  }
  
  public void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     Item changedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
         if (changedItem == null)
           return;
     Log.Info("ITEM SAVING"); 
  }

  public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
     Item changedItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
         if (changedItem == null)
           return;
     Log.Info("ITEM SAVED");
  }
}
```

There are 2 issues here:

1. In the `OnItemCreated` method, the `createdItem` is always null. But in quick watch, I can see the created item.
   And so, the `Log.Info` method is never getting executed here.
2. After the `OnItemCreated`, the `OnItemSaving` method is triggered and then the `OnItemSaved`.  Both the save methods get the item data. But these two methods are triggered twice.

So, the logs are like:

2023-07-04 10:00:01 ITEM SAVING
2023-07-04 10:00:02 ITEM SAVED
2023-07-04 10:00:03 ITEM SAVING
2023-07-04 10:00:04 ITEM SAVED

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
 Item createdItem = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
```

use the following code:

```
ItemCreatedEventArgs itemCreatedEventArgs = Event.ExtractParameter<ItemCreatedEventArgs>(args, 0);
var createdItem = itemCreatedEventArgs.Item;
```

`OnItemSaving` and `OnItemSaved` methods are executed twice because of how Sitecore works:

- first item is created only with name and template - that's then first set of events is triggered
- then other item fields are set - that's when events are triggered again.

Comment: Thank you. That worked!!!